# Choise wich OS to boot in NOOBS with gpio

Tags: pi-zero, noobs

Well, I have RPi0w and I need to boot different os when at example I boot from pc or just regular power supplay, without keyboard and mouse. 
So I decided use gpio as OS choiser... But how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The Pi offers no support for booting a different operating system dependent on the GPIO.